# Bottom toolbar button is not clickable in PhoneJS

Tags: phonejs

I am new to PhoneJS. I add toolbar as bottomToolBar and button in it then click event is not working in android any more. if I add toolbar as topToolBar then everything work fine.
It's working fine in IOS and desktop as bottom and top both.I don't use any layout in my application.

Comment: Not enough details to assist you. Try to contact [DevExpress support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).